# Vue: when to use @keyup.native in input elements

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue component with

1. an `<input>` element that binds the `v-on:keyup.enter` key to `doFilter()`
2. a `<button>` that binds the `v-on:click` event to `doFilter()`

```html
<input type="text" v-model="myVar" @keyup.enter="doFilter" />
<button @click="doFilter">Filter</button>
```

The button event will fire `doFilter()`, but the key up event will not fire, unless I add the `.native` modifier.

```
<input type="text" v-model="myVar" @keyup.native.enter="doFilter" />
```

The [Vue.js documentation says this about](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) `.native`:

> listen for a native event on the root element of component.

When do I need to use `.native` and why does the keyup event not trigger without it?

## Update 1: Add codepen and code

Runnable demo at https://codepen.io/hanxue/pen/Zapmra

```
<div id="app">
  <md-toolbar>
    <h1 class="md-title" style="flex: 1">@keyup.native event</h1>
    <md-button class="md-icon-button">
      <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
    </md-button>
  </md-toolbar>
  
  <md-input-container>
      <label>@keyup.enter</label>
              <md-input type="text" @keyup.enter="doFilter" placeholder="@keyup.filter">
              </md-input>
          </md-input-container>
  
    <md-input-container>       
        <label>@keyup.native.enter</label>
              <md-input type="text" @keyup.native.enter="doFilter" placeholder="@keyup.native.filter">
              </md-input>
          </md-input-container>
  
    <md-input-container>       
              <button @click="doFilter" placeholder="@keyup.filter">
    @click  </button>
          </md-input-container>
</div>
<script>
Vue.use(VueMaterial)

var App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
   doFilter: function() {
     alert('doFilter!')
   }
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: Weird, their page doesn't show any key modifier called native. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers For the first part, isn't `@keyup.enter="doFilter"` saying call `doFilter` when the user types enter?

Comment: It's at this page https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on
That's right, I expect `@keyup.enter="doFilter"` to work, but it doesn't. Only when I change it to `@keyup.native.enter="doFilter"` it works

Comment: I can't reproduce this: https://jsfiddle.net/y7hm78dy/. Can you post a fiddle of this happening? Is it really an `<input>` element, or is it a component that wraps an input element, (like `<el-input>` or similar) and you've just simplified your example?

Comment: Indeed I am using vuematerial.io 's `<md-input>`. The code is pretty complex, I will try to produce a fiddle or codepen

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'm assuming that you're using the [Vue Material libary](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material) and the `<md-input>` component instead of an `<input>` element.

If you listen to the `keyup` event without using the `.native` modifier (via `<md-input @keyup.enter="doFilter">`), then your component is waiting for the `<md-input>` component to emit a custom `keyup` event.

[But, that component does not emit a `keyup` event](http://vuematerial.io/#/components/input), so the `doFilter` method will never be called.

[As the documentation states](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components), adding the `.native` modifier will make the component listen for a "native event on the root element" of the `<md-input>` component.

So, `<md-input @keyup.native.enter="doFilter">` will listen to the native `keyup` DOM event of the root element of the `<md-input>` component and call the `doFilter` method when that is triggered from the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a custom vue component on which I was listening to both `@select` and `@keyup.native.enter`  and I was receiving the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key twice because I didn't pay attention: `onSelect` emits an `onKeyDown` for <kbd>Enter</kbd>and `onkeyUp` flared secondly.

My solution was to listen to `@keydown.native.enter` so that the `@select` cycle of keys was unbothered (which is `keydown` -> `keypresssed` -> `keyup`).